# Passing an array of objects to child component rendered within iteration returns undefined error in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-props

I have a feeling I'm running into problems with nested attributes but even using Truthy && methods to avoid `undefined`, I'm still not able to get passed an undefined error.

I have a Set and an Array of Objects that are being passed down to a child component. The Set is converted to an Array which is iterated over. Within the iteration is where I wish to access the key/value pairs of the Array of Objects. So it looks like this:

```
<MainPadding>
        {[...selectedCity].map((city, idx) => (
          <Row key={city.id}>
            <Col sm={12} md={6} mdOffset={4} lgOffset={4}>
              <Typography h3>{city.name}</Typography>
              <Typography className="hide-mobile" h3>
                TICKET PRICE FOR IN-STATE:
              </Typography>
              <TicketPriceInput
                onChange={e => {
                  setLocationPrices(e.target.value, idx, city.id);
                  detectInputChange(e);
                }}
                value={locationPrices[idx].price} // *** THE PROBLEM IS HERE ***
                name="price"
                isPriceChanged={isPriceChanged}
              />

              <OutPriceLabel className="hide-mobile">
                <Typography h3>TICKET PRICE FOR OUT-OF-STATE:</Typography>
                <Typography h3 bold className="hide-mobile">
                  {outLocationPrice(locationPrices[idx].price)} // *** AND HERE ***
                </Typography>
              </OutPriceLabel>

              <FootNote>
                <Typography medium spaced className="hide-mobile">
                  *After the first 20 tickets anyone located in-state can
                  purchase tickets at the regular ticket price you set.
                </Typography>
              </FootNote>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        ))}
        ;
      </MainPadding>
```

The error is `'price' is undefined`. Even if I try something like `locationPrices && locationPrices[idx].price` or `selectedCities && locationPrices[idx].price`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you made sure the data actually exists? i.e. at that index, it has a price attribute?

Comment: Ok that's exactly what the problem is. There's nothing there yet. Which leads to the next question: how do I dynamically build the object as data is entered?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to only render the component when you have the data, like so:

```js
{
  Array.isArray(locationPrices) && locationPrices[idx].price && (
    <TicketPriceInput
      onChange={(e) => {
        setLocationPrices(e.target.value, idx, city.id);
        detectInputChange(e);
      }}
      value={locationPrices[idx].price} // *** THE PROBLEM IS HERE ***
      name='price'
      isPriceChanged={isPriceChanged}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it too much to ask for a component to 1) build a form dynamically, build an incoming prop dynamically as an array of added objects based on form size and 3) use that dynamically built up object prop as a state to control the form input? Or do I need to try a different strategy?

Comment: It's absolutely not too much to ask, the thing is, I don't know where or how the data is coming in. It is from some sort of fetch function? or async operation? because if that is the case, then you will always need to write the component so that it can handle an empty state.